# why the height of a frame is not constant in ie7

Tags: javascript, html, css

i was developing a page which has two frames, the left frame is a treeview file, when click one of the file it will display on the right frame.the main page code is below

```
<frameset  id="main_frame" cols="210,*" rows="*">
            <frame src="FramesetLeftFrame.jsp" id="treeframe" noresize="noresize"/>
            <frame src=""  id="basefrm" noresize="noresize"/>
</frameset>
```

the question is the treeview display correctly in chrome and firefox, but in ie7 the treeview becomes **auto-height**!when i click a folder with the files becomes more the height becomes higher.how can i fix the problem? i have tried add a min-height = 100% or height = 100%,it does not work.
   by the way, the tree is maked by javascript. FramesetLeftFrame.jsp is below:

```
  <SCRIPT src="ua.js"></SCRIPT>

  <!-- Infrastructure code for the TreeView. DO NOT REMOVE.    -->
  <SCRIPT src="ftiens4.js"></SCRIPT>

   <!-- Scripts that define the tree. DO NOT REMOVE. -->
   <%@include file="buildTree.jsp" %>

 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
      <SCRIPT>initializeDocument()</SCRIPT>
          <NOSCRIPT>
            A tree for site navigation will open here if you enable JavaScript in your browser.
          </NOSCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: the doc type are all
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

Comment: Can you show a live example? Also, are you 100% sure this is the frame's fault and not of the treeview?

Comment: it works fine in chrome and firefox, i don't think this is the js error. even when i moved the script it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

First off, why have you added the asterisk (*) to your cols etc?? Try remove them:

```
<frameset  id="main_frame" cols="210" rows="">
```

Secondly, try using css inline styles to define your width and height like so:

```
<frameset  id="main_frame" style="width:200px; height:400px;">...
```

Does that make a difference? You could of course have those style in an external style sheet (better practice) and link them to your id #main_frame